# IIS not passing PHP sessions in IE?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, iis, iis-8

So i have this mulitple page php app that inserts the data into sql database. This is what i have noticed:

**Using Xampp:**
The application works fine with Chrome and IE11. The variable are being transferred using `session_start()`, like they are supposed to.

Page1.html sends data to Page2.php; and then Page2.php sends data to Page3.php and it stores it in database. Some of the data sent to page3 is from page1.

**Using IIS:**
The application works fine in Chrome like it is supposed to.

In IE11, the database is blank. Data is not being transferred using session. 
After debugging i noticed: 
Page1.html sends data to Page2.php, but Page2.php is not sending data to Page3.php.

Any ideas why this is happening. Is there a setting on IIS, I dont think its the code since it is working on Xampp. But i could be wrong, any ideas?

Comment: @chris85 It is literally the first few lines on the php section of page3. I have `session_start()` as first line, and then `$var = $_SESSION['var']; echo $var`

Comment: Oh, yea actually the JS would still execute the same under IIS and xampp. Nothing in the logs? The page is throwing a 500?

Comment: php sessions are just cookies. you need to check if the session cookie is properly propagating, and whether `session_id()` is consistent between your pages.

Comment: @MarcB how do i do this?